# How can I give certain colour on certain groups in R plot function?

Tags: r, plot, colors

I'm trying to give my tsne plot few different colour label.

What I scripted is

```
plot(XXX.tsne,
     col=c("red", "blue")[
                    grepl("A|B|C|D|E", colnames(dta.log))+1], 
     cex=0.5, pch=19)
```

XXX.tsne has been given above already.

It gives two colours to my plot, but now I need to combine more than two colours in a same plot, i.e. A|B|C|D|E= blue,  F|G|H|I=yellow and k|l|m|n =red.

I think `grepl` function would not be useful here. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `grepl` which is only giving you two values use the `match` function;. You didn't offer a test case but perhaps something like:

```
<other args>,
col=c("red", "blue")[
       match( colnames(dta.log),c("A","B","C","D","E") )],..
```

The `match` function is 1-based and designed for exactly this purpose rather than needing to have +1 bump. You may need to watch out for items in the `dta.log` object that do not match those options. See the `?match` page for your exception handling if needed.